# TDD In practice -- How do you write a unit test for sending an email?

Tags: unit-testing, coding-style, tdd

Client says he wants a button that when pushed, takes the form below and sends it as an email. How would you unit test this?

Assume you are:

- Using an existing SMTP library
- Using an existing IMAP library

From what I understand, you could use a UI mocker to click the button, then wait a minute or so, then use IMAP to count if there is one more message received than before. But this sounds like it violates TDD goals in almost every category -- it's not fast, it's not atomic, it's complex, it requires it's own IMAP dependency. What's the "TDD" way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What part of **YOUR** program do you want to test?

Please note what I highlighted there - you want to test *your code*.

You do not test things out of your control unless you absolutely need to. So, I would say, if you use SMTP/IMAP libraries - you trust that they do what they are supposed to, you don't write tests to verify that, similarly as you don't check the `File.write()` actually writes to file, etc.

Back to your question, please look into creating and adapter/simulator for email behavior. Use in-memory implementation in your test, and use *the real thing* in your production code.

Eric Gunnerson has written a [good post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2014/12/01/unit-test-success-using-ports-adapters-and-simulators.aspx) about them as well as published a [kata](https://github.com/ericgu/RecipeManagerKataV2) to github